# Top-level functions privately sharing a scope

Tags: functional-programming, scheme

In scheme, it is possible to use `set!` to create two (or more) functions which share a private scope between them:

```
(define f1 #f) ; or any other "undefined" value
(define f2 #f)

(let ((private some-value) (another-private some-other-value))
  (set! f1 (lambda ... <use of private variables> ...))
  (set! f2 (lambda ... <use of private variables> ...)))
```

or by using a third variable:

```
(define functions
  (let ((private some-value) (another-private some-other-value))
    (list (lambda ... <use of private variables> ...)
          (lambda ... <use of private variables> ...))))

(define f1 (car functions))
(define f2 (cadr functions))
```

However, both of these seem inelegant, due to the use of `set!` in the first and the left-over variable `functions` in the second. Is there a way to do this without either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(define-values (f1 f2)
  (let ((private values) ...)
    (values (lambda ...)
            (lambda ...))))
```

Comment: Thanks! Just one thing, the second line should read `(let ((private values) ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Not every scheme implementation provides define-values.  There's a macro definition on the schemers wiki:

```
(define-syntax define-values 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((define-values () exp) 
     (call-with-values (lambda () exp) (lambda () 'unspecified))) 
    ((define-values (var . vars) exp) 
     (begin  
       (define var (call-with-values (lambda () exp) list)) 
       (define-values vars (apply values (cdr var))) 
       (define var (car var)))) 
    ((define-values var exp) 
     (define var (call-with-values (lambda () exp) list)))))
```

http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-macros